# Can I use CKEditor with minimum options?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can I remove buttons from the CKEditor toolbar without changing js

is there way to add script for remove icons.

[image: this is my current view of]
this is my current view of CKEditor

Thanks for your time and help.

**SOLUTION**

I Found Solution to display specific icons on CKEditor toolbar

```
CKEDITOR.config.removeButtons = 'Source';
```

you can check complete list of toolbar names here

```
http://www.ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Complete-list-of-toolbar-items
```

Comment: You should just select the appropriate option on the CKEditor download page... http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and when possible mark it as "the answer" for your question.